# How can I bind dynamic input box array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

There is my data.

```
{
  "columns":[ "first_name", "last_name", "email", "country", "age", "gender" ],
  "peoples":[
    {
      "first_name":"Anik",
      "last_name":"Datta",
      "email":"aunik@mail.me",
      "custom_fields":{
        "age":17,
        "gender":"male"
      }
    },
    {
      "first_name":"John",
      "last_name":"Doe",
      "email":"john@mail.me",
      "custom_fields":{

      },
     {
      "first_name":"John",
      "last_name":"Doe",
      "email":"john@mail.me",
      "custom_fields":{
        "age": 22
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to show these on textbox like this,
labels will be data from columns, and below, there will be text boxes filled with data from "peoples" key.

`first_name`   `last_name`    `email`    `country`   `age`   `gender`
textboxes  are appearing below following column names.

template:

```html
<div class="peoples">
  <h5>Peoples</h5>
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="column in columns"
      :class="`col-${Math.ceil(12/columns.length}`">
      <label>{{$t(column)}}</label>
      <app-input
        :key="index"
        :name="column + index"
        :id="column + index"
        v-for="(contacts, index) in peoples"
        :value="setFieldValues(contacts, column)"
        />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

script:

```js
    data() {
            return {
                contacts: [],
            }
        },

        methods: {

            setFieldValues(contacts, column) {

                if (contacts['custom_fields'][column] !== undefined) {
                     return contacts['custom_fields'][column];
                }
                if (contacts[column] !== undefined) {
                    return contacts[column];
                }
            }
        },
```

it can fill data well but in the console, there are 61 errors showing because there was no 2-way binding with data.
How can I  bind these dynamic fields in data in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This might help, change the template to this:

```
<template v-for="(contacts, index) in peoples">
    <template v-if="contacts['custom_fields'][column] !== undefined">
        <app-input
            :key="index"
            :name="column + index"
            :id="column + index"
            v-for="(contacts, index) in peoples"
            v-model="contacts['custom_fields'][column]"
        />
    </template>
    <template v-else-if="contacts[column] !== undefined">
        <app-input
            :key="index"
            :name="column + index"
            :id="column + index"
            v-for="(contacts, index) in peoples"
            v-model="contacts[column]"
        />
    </template>
</template>
```

I didn't try out the code but it should give you the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-model to make a two way data binding. See this example (I have modified your code a little bit to make runnable).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    "columns": ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "country", "age", "gender"],
    "peoples": [{
        "first_name": "Anik",
        "last_name": "Datta",
        "email": "aunik@mail.me",
        "custom_fields": {
          "age": 17,
          "gender": "male"
        }
      },
      {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "john@mail.me",
        "custom_fields": {

        }
      },
      {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "john@mail.me",
        "custom_fields": {
          "age": 22
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div class="peoples">
    <h5>Peoples</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div v-for="column in columns" :class="`col-${Math.ceil(12/columns.length)}`">
        <label>{{column}}</label>
        <input :key="index" :name="column + index" :id="column + index" v-for="(contacts, index) in peoples" v-model="contacts[column]" />
      </div>
    </div>
    {{peoples}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed `:value` to `v-model` in the example. Now it is reactive.